# Configure Absolutepath for standalone Applications for case of log4j2.xml

Tags: log4j2

Was using log4j.xml in my standalone application with programeticallu injecting the Absolute Path as defined

DOMConfigurator.configure("/realpathofxml/log4.xml")

but now would like to `log4j2.xml` instead of `log42.xml`

How to inject the Absolute path to initialize log4j2.xml ?

with regards
karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///absolute/path/to/log4j2.xml");
Configurator.initialize("my app", null, uri);
```

Comment: Hi

Thx this worked  "Configurator.initialize("my app", null, uri);"

Answer (score 0):

You can  specify the full path of the configuration file with this system property:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
```

See also 
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location

Comment: Hi ... I would like to use from within the Java Code  as similar to  DOMConfigurator.configure  and not via argument based...  Thx Karthik

Comment: Ok then better to ask on the log4j-user mailing list: that's where the experts hang out...